# How to trigger an Airflow dag from different GCP project?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have two independent DAGs let's say **DAG_A** and **DAG_B**, each has multiple tasks

The two DAGs are in different GCP projects let's say **projct-1** and **project-2** respectively.

- What I want to do is to create a 3rd DAG let's call it **DAG_C**
- **DAG_C** will be part of **project-1** , and will be used to orchestrate **DAG_A** and **DAG_B**.
- **DAG_C** should start by triggering **DAG_A** and on **task_2** success it should trigger **DAG_B**

Please take a look at this picture that simplifies the problem:
[Overview of the architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmQH0.png)

**The question is**: would this be possible using the **TriggerDagRunOperator** , as I can't see any option to change the GCP project id on that operator ?

Also what would be the best approach to go towards that "assuming that TriggerDagRunOperator will not work in that case" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to do that with `TriggerDagRunOperator` as the operator see only the scope of the Airflow instance that it's in.

Your only option is to use the Airflow [Rest API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html).
In `DAG_C` the `trigger_B` task will need to be a `PythonOperator` that authenticate with the Rest API of `project_2` and then use the [Trigger new DagRun](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) endpoint to trigger `DAG_B`. Note that Airflow provides [official Python client](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python) for the API so you can use it for this task.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to do it by authenticating using airflow client id to get the token (I had to give project-1 composer service account [Composer User] role in project-2 , then did a normal POST request using requests.request(). 
I wasn't aware of that official python client though, may give it a try :)